# clicked() signal for QWidget breaks stylesheets

Tags: qt, inheritance, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I want to connect clicked() signal of QWidget-container to my slot. So I wrote this code:

hpp:

```
class LinkWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit LinkWidget(QWidget * parent = 0 );
    ~LinkWidget();

signals:
    void clicked();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event ) ;
};
```

cpp:

```
LinkWidget::LinkWidget(QWidget * parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{

}

LinkWidget::~LinkWidget()
{

}

void LinkWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    emit clicked();
}
```

Everything works fine, but I can't assign stylesheet to this widget anymore:

That works:

```
QWidget * statuspanel = new QWidget(this);
statuspanel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
statuspanel->setMinimumHeight(20);
statuspanel->setMaximumHeight(20);
statuspanel->setStyleSheet("border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(206, 203, 186);"
                           "border-right : 1px solid rgb(206, 203, 186);");
```

That doesn't:

```
LinkWidget * statuspanel = new LinkWidget(this);
statuspanel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
statuspanel->setMinimumHeight(20);
statuspanel->setMaximumHeight(20);
statuspanel->setStyleSheet("border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(206, 203, 186);"
                           "border-right : 1px solid rgb(206, 203, 186);");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is you aren't subclassing QWidget properly, some code might be missing in the LinkWidget class

Comment: No sure if it might help, but you can try: statuspanel->setStyleSheet("LinkWidget{border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(206, 203, 186); border-right : 1px solid rgb(206, 203, 186);}");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to stylesheets work for direct `QWidget` subclasses you should reimplement the `paintEvent` method:

```
void LinkWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```