# Why does QWidget disappear after promoted?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qwidget

I have a hierarchy of 3 widgets:

[image]

Each widget has the background color changed to a different color(using QSS) so that the output looks like:

[image]

All good here. But if I promote `widget` to a class derived from QWidget it disappears like so:

[image]

[image]

This is the code for my `Custom` widget:

custom.h:

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_H
#define CUSTOM_H

#include <QWidget>

class Custom : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Custom(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

#endif // CUSTOM_H
```

custom.cpp:

```
#include "custom.h"

Custom::Custom(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
}
```

Can anybody explain why are these weird things happening and what can I do to make the green widget show up??

Comment: What does the QSS look like?

Comment: `background-color: red;`, `background-color: green;` and `background-color: blue;` applied on each widget using the Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago I have already answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020180/clicked-signal-for-qwidget-breaks-stylesheets) :)

In order to qss stylesheets work for direct `QWidget` subclasses you should implement the `paintEvent` like this:

```
void Custom::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```

Comment: now this is a million dollar answer!!
but make me understand...why do we have to do this? what changes? I reimplemented the paint event and forwarded the event to `QWidget` but didn't think about redrawing it. Why do we have to redraw it?

Comment: I think when a QWidget draws itslef it does not apply any stylesheets, that's why you should implement the paint event. You can read about it in the official doc at the QWidget section: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html

Answer (score -1):

For QLineEdit, remember to call/inherit base class like this constructor

```
QLineEdit_KPE::QLineEdit_KPE(QWidget *parent) : 
QLineEditt(parent)
{
}
```